# When adding an object to an ArrayList, other object with an ArrayList as attribute that are already in the list get modified?

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring, observablelist

At the moment I have a class "Test" with an observableList of "Question" Objects and an ArrayList of "Question" Objects.

Each Object has the following attributes:
 - private String question;
   private ArrayList statements;
   private String category;
   private String feedback;

When I add a new Question-object to the lists. My old objects (that are already in the list) get changed. The attribute ArrayList statements become the value of the last added object-ArrayList statements

First i thought that the .add methode off an observableList had some special functie, that's why i added an arrayList but it doesn't change anything.

I did some 'system.out.println' to show the problem.

Class Test:

```
package model;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test {
    private ObservableList<Category> categories;
    private ObservableList<Question> questions;
    private ArrayList<Question> questionArray;



public Test () {
    categories = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    questions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    questionArray = new ArrayList<>();
}


public ObservableList<Category> getCategories(){
    return categories;
}

public ObservableList<Question> getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}

public void addCategory(Category category){
    categories.add(category);
}

public void addQuestion(Question question){
    questions.add(question);
}

public void makeCategories(ArrayList<String> elementen) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementen.size(); i += 3) {
            String naam = elementen.get(i);
            String description = elementen.get(i + 1);
            String hoofdCategorie = elementen.get(i + 2);
            Category category = null;
            if (hoofdCategorie.equals("null")) {
                category = new Category(naam, description);
            } else {
                category = new Category(naam, description, hoofdCategorie);
            }
            categories.add(category);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ModelException("Categorie aanmaken is niet gelukt");
    }
}


public void makeQuestions(ArrayList<String> primitieveQuestions) {
    ArrayList <String> statements = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < primitieveQuestions.size();i+=4) {
        String question = primitieveQuestions.get(i);
        String category = primitieveQuestions.get(i+1);
        String feedback = primitieveQuestions.get(i+2);
        String primitieveStatements = primitieveQuestions.get(i+3);
        statements.clear();
        for (String woord:primitieveStatements.split("\\s",0)) {
            statements.add(woord);
        }
        Question x = new Question(question, statements, category, feedback);
        System.out.println("object");
        System.out.println(x.toString());


        questions.add(x);
        questionArray.add(x);

        // magic

        System.out.println("observableList");
        for (Question y : questions) {
            System.out.println(y.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("array");
        for (Question y : questionArray) {
            System.out.println(y.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(" ");

    }
}
}
```

Class Question

```
package model;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Question {
    private String question;
    private ArrayList<String> statements;
    private String category;
private String feedback;

public Question (String question, ArrayList<String> statements, String category, String feedback ) {
    setQuestion(question);
    setStatements(statements);
    setCategory(category);
    setFeedback(feedback);
}

public Question (String question, ObservableList<String> statements, String category, String feedback ) {
    setQuestion(question);
    for (String x : statements) {
        setStringStatements(x);
    }
    setCategory(category);
    setFeedback(feedback);
}

//getters
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public ArrayList<String> getStatements() {
    return statements;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public String getFeedback() {
    return feedback;
}

//Setters
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
//setter van een meegegeven arrayList
public void setStatements(ArrayList<String> statements) {
    this.statements = statements;
}

//setters als we een string aan onze lijst van statments willen toevoegen
public void setStringStatements(String statement) {
    this.statements.add(statement);
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public void setFeedback(String feedback) {
    this.feedback = feedback;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  category + " " + statements;
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
object
Design Patterns [Strategy, Facade, Observer, State]
observableList
Design Patterns [Strategy, Facade, Observer, State]
array
Design Patterns [Strategy, Facade, Observer, State]

object
Design principles [Juist, Fout, fout, fout]
observableList
Design Patterns [Juist, Fout, fout, fout]
Design principles [Juist, Fout, fout, fout]
array
Design Patterns [Juist, Fout, fout, fout]
Design principles [Juist, Fout, fout, fout]

object
principe [ik, wordt, zot]
observableList
Design Patterns [ik, wordt, zot]
Design principles [ik, wordt, zot]
principe [ik, wordt, zot]
array
Design Patterns [ik, wordt, zot]
Design principles [ik, wordt, zot]
principe [ik, wordt, zot]
```

Please take note how the ArrayList-attribute of each object in the list gets altered. It gets the value of the last added objet his ArrayList-attribute.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You might want to read how to creat a [MCVE]. Your code is complete (kudos for that!) but it looks like it isn't minimal. E.g. it contains a lot of stuff probably not needed to reproduce the issue. For example I can imagine that reducing the classes to one getter and setter, and reducing the example to one ObservableList instead of two, would make the code much easier to read and understand.

Comment: You are using _the same_ `ArrayList` in multiple question objects. Move the `ArrayList <String> statements = new ArrayList();` in the `for`-loop (replacing the `statements.clear()`).

Comment: @MaxVollmer I think it can be (and is in this case) too much to expect of *new* programmers to wrench their code around to minimal in all cases. Many of them are still figuring out what is necessary and what isn't, and are just learning the very basics of what it is in programs that does what the program does. I don't have any problem with it in many cases, but newbies' frustration could understandably increase by being told there's something *else* they should do before even asking a question. And we can often help them without it, as demonstrated here.

Comment: This Question is not clear. Try to simplify. If you want help free-of-cost, keep the cognitive burden low. Delete all the stuff you may care about but we don't need to know.

Comment: I understand the concerns about the messy code.
First of all i'm still a student at the University of Leuven Belgium. This code is for a group-assignment. The assigment is to build a "Quiz" with multiple questions.
We work in an agile-fashion. So we work user-story after user-story on our code.
Because we have to work on the code with 3 - 4 people, who still struggle with some basic concepts like the observableList, we use silly methodes like: "does is work if I use an arrayList instead off an observableList ? 

Can anyone explain me why Michael Butscher solution works?
Pardon my english

Comment: Java works with references to objects. Assigning an object to a variable (or using it as parameter of a call) copies only the reference which points to the same object as before. Modifying the object modifies it for all holders of the reference. My code change creates a `new` object for each question so every question object has its own `ArrayList` object.